# Magento 2: Cannot set cookie when full page cache is enabled

Tags: php, caching, cookies, magento2, amasty

I have this **working** code for setting the cookie for a visitor:

```
$metadata = $cookieMetadataFactory
    ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
    ->setDuration(86400 * 90)
    ->setPath('/');
$cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
    'cookie_name',
    'cookie_value',
    $metadata
);
```

But, since I enabled full page cache for the website, this code stopped working.
Disabling cache is not a option, using javascript is not a option...

I noticed that other extensions that use cookies (like Amasty Affiliate), also don't work.
Is this default Magento behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the Full Page Cache (FPC) is interfering together with your cookie putting capability. When FPC is enabled, the page content material is cached, so your server-aspect code for setting the cookie isn't always being carried out on every page load. Here are some steps you could observe to solve this difficulty:

**Utilize AJAX:** Use an AJAX call to a server-aspect action to set the cookie, thereby isolating the cookie putting from page rendering.

```
       // AJAX example using jQuery
$.ajax({
    url: 'your/server/side/action',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
        // success handling
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // error handling
    }
});
```

On the server-facet, you will take care of cookie putting as regular.

**HTTP Cookies:**

Set cookies via HTTP headers through web server configuration or a reverse proxy. **Custom Cache Contexts:**

Establish a custom cache context or a cacheable block in Magento to manipulate cookies at the same time as maintaining FPC enabled. Extension Configurations:

Check configurations of any third-party extensions installed, some might have solutions for managing cookies with FPC.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Do you think that this is default Magento behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, when a full-page cache is enabled, you may encounter issues setting cookies. Full-page caching saves complete HTML pages and serves them to users, making it challenging to set dynamic cookies for personalized user experiences. To work around this, you can use client-side JavaScript to set cookies after the page loads. This ensures that cookies are still effective while benefiting from full-page caching.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).